# Trying to Test for NoneType or Empty Cell in DataFrame but Method is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that I'm trying to tidy up and clean out.

I'm basically testing for any cell in column 'Header 3' that is empty, and if it is, then I delete the row.

Unfortunately everything I've tried to highlight if the cell is empty doesn't appear to be working.

I've checked the cell I'm validating the method against, and it comes up as None when I check it as a string and also as a NoneType when I check the type.

I've tried checking using `if cell == 'nan'` and also if it equals None but neither appear to catch the cell.

```
if str(import_sheet.loc[23,'Header 3']) == 'nan':
    print('Yep')
else:
    print('Nope')

if str(import_sheet.loc[23,'Header 3']) == None:
    print('Yep')
else:
    print('Nope')

Nope
Nope

print(str(import_sheet.loc[23,'Header 3']))
print(type(import_sheet.loc[23,'Header 3']))


None
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`isnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.isnull.html) function instead of `str(...) == 'nan'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.dropna()` method of Pandas:

```
import_sheet = import_sheet.dropna(subset = ['Header 3'])
```

Documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).